# How to get results from database on typing and match all data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 'location search' functionality on my website, where I can search locations. For example if I search for 'new york' I get the result, but if I search for the location by the first word 'l' or using the word 'new' or missing any character from the word 'new york' , I get nothing.

the JS:

```
document.getElementById('text-input').addEventListener('keyup' , searchLocation);
```

searchLocation function makes AJAX request to a PHP file that connects the Database and return matches.

Here is the code inside the PHP file:

```
$query = $_POST['q'];
$pattern = '/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*$/';
if(preg_match($pattern, $query)){
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM users WHERE location SOUNDS LIKE  :s
         GROUP BY location
        );');
        $stmt->bindValue(':s', '%' . $query . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $value = $stmt->fetch();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($count > 0){
                echo $value['location'];
        }else{
            echo 'No Results Found';
        }
}
```

I have to type the whole word and even if there is a miss spelling word like 'now york' , It would find 'new york'.

But if I type 'n' or 'new' , I get No Results Found.

How to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql statement uses the [sounds like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) operator, which is used to compare how two strings sound (pronounced). You need to use the simple `like` operator for matching substrings:

```
... WHERE location LIKE  :s
```

Comment: Will I get the right location if I entered 'now york'?

Comment: Nope, you would not. That's a lot more complicated. I doubt that new york and now york are pronounced the same anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use approximate string matching(fuzzy search). Please check the link below, there is a simple example that you can use.

https://github.com/wataridori/simple-fuzzy-search